# call main method in java module using JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I've been trying to call the main method of a class and pass it some arguments.

My code is as below:

```
args = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 2, myClass, NULL);
arg1 = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello");
arg2 = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, World!");
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, args, 0, arg1);
(*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, args, 1, arg2);
(*env)->CallStaticVoidMethod(env, myClass, mainMethod, args);
```

But it seems that it doesn't work.
When I print the `args` array in the java code it prints null.

Comment: Do you mean  `"World!"` instead of  `World!"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an Array of "myClass" instead of String

```
stringClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/String");
args = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, 2, stringClass, NULL);
```